# Table rounds up values to whole numbers even though data type in tables is decimal

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image]

The DynEff column is a measure I created which simply sums the refCalculations[StdHrs] column. However, for some reason the table is rounding off the values to whole number. In PQ, the column type is decimal. In the Data view in PBI as well, the type is decimal. But for some reason when I add the measure to the table, values get displayed as whole numbers!

I know the values are correct. Is this just a display issue? I have other measures in the table with simple sum formulas that don't get rounded off. For example, DynLbs is also a simple sum and I get the correct value, with decimals!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

In Report View, select the field in question, Column Tools, you will see a Formatting group where you can choose the correct formatting.